# Building development portfolio in Image processing domain

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I come from the domain of digital signal processing including images, videos and audios. I have development experience in C, Python and Matlab. I would like to know how i can go about building a development portfolio in this domain. I havent done much outside of my job and would really like to do some coding in the domain but cant seem to find the right kind of problems to solve. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try contributing to Open Source projects like [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues).

Comment: This is not the place for this question. Post in reddit forums specifically for these kind of things to get good answers. To answer your question, I would suggest choose the programming language you are comfortable with and go to kaggle.com and try solving some problems. Image processing is vast so you need to be sure as to what specific kind of problems you like.